# Как обновить Windows 10 до 1903 при ошибке "Не удалось обновить раздел, зарезервированный системой"

Tags: windows, windows-10, установка, ssd, обновления

При обновлении Windows 10 до 1903 получаю сообщение об ошибке: "**Не удалось обновить раздел, зарезервированный системой**". Но такого раздела у меня нет. На диске (ssd 256) есть:

1. "Восстановить" (Раздел изготовителя оборудования)
2. "Шифрованный (EFI) системный раздел"
3. С: (Загрузка, Основной раздел)

Для первых двух букву назначить невозможно. Поэтому бродящая по интернету инструкция для устранения такой ошибки (takeown, attrib, etc.) не применима.

В чем может быть дело, как обновить до 1903?

**upd**: Сегодня Windows передумал и сказал, что "мое устройство не совсем готово", но причин не объяснил и велел ждать 1903 для "совместимых устройств". Обновление стало недоступно.

Comment: А вы не в курсе, как так получилось, что его у вас нет? Обычно винда создаёт его при установке автоматически в обязательном порядке

Comment: @andreymal, получилось в результате работы инсталлятора windows, никаких специальных действий по созданию/удалению разделов не предпринималось

Comment: И как решился вопрос по обновлению винды?

Comment: @ВладимирОрлов, никак, к сожалению. начинает обновляться, упирается в ошибку, предлагает исправить и далее по кругу. никакие изменения прав, владельцев и т.д. на отдельные системные папки, как рекомендуют в сетях, эффекта не дают.

Comment: У меня короче была windows 10 Lite и там было тоже самое, к ним не предусматривалось обновляться выше чего-то, ещё был комп с windows 10 server, там тоже такое было. Помогла просто установка обычной windows 10

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, В смысле Windows 10 Lite?

Comment: @VadimPedchenko ой, перепутал, не lite, а Windows 10 Enteprise LTSB

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла вот эта инструкция =>
https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/3086249/we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows

У меня был вариант с => Windows 10 с разделом GPT.

Правда там ошибка "del q." (надо вводить "del *.*")